# App Center stuck on 'waiting'

Tags: applications, appcenter

I'm on a fresh install.

At first, when I was trying to install an app from the app center it would say 'starting' with an empty loading bar that would remain empty forever.

After looking up some solutions I tried running 
   `sudo apt update` and 
    `sudo apt upgrade`,
now when I try to install an app the behavior is essentially identical except it now says 'Waiting' instead of 'starting'.

**EDIT:** the problem no longer exists for me on 0.4.1 with the new App Center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue yesterday. I tried the update and upgrade as you said, rebooting and nothing happened. Then I followed these steps to remove and install again the AppCenter and now it's fixed. I hope it will work for you as well.

```
1.sudo apt-get purge appcenter
2.sudo apt-get purge packagekit
3.Restart
4.sudo apt-get install packagekit
5.sudo apt-get install appcenter
6.Restart
```

Edit: You can also update manually with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
Restart
```

In response to the comment you wrote.

Comment: I followed the steps you have outlined but to no avail :(

Comment: @banana1 sorry to hear that. I can't think of anything else, I am new in elementary OS. I tried several things myself but this is what helped me. Give it a try to do the `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` with a reboot after each command. Because I see you didn't use the -get part.

Comment: For me this did also not work. But was the best suggestion until now.

Comment: I had a different AppCenter issue: "Updates" tab totally blank despite notifications saying updates are available.  This solution seemed to fix that problem, at least.

Comment: @D.Hancock I had this issue. It must be a bug. If this answer helped you, please upvote it. thank you.

Comment: @D.Hancock I had the exact same issue today. I now have the gnome software app installed and the updating worked fine there. it was an OS update nonetheless!

Comment: @banana1 Check the edited answer and mark this as accepted answer if it works for you. Thank you.

Comment: @geo1230 the manual updates were never an issue, they do work. the problem remains with the App Center

Comment: @banana1 I didn't say that there was a problem, just as an easy way to update ;)

Answer (score 0):

open terminal and type:

`sudo apt update`

Then reboot when it's done updating.

Answer (score -1):

1. Sudo dpkg --configure -a
2. Sudo apt-get update
3. Reboot
4. Open system settings
5. Click about
6. Check for update
7. Reboot

Done